# Unable to Connect Sql server using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, authentication, database-connection

I am not able to connect to sql server using Windows Authentication .[image]
[image]

Comment: is the SQL Server Express started ?

Comment: No,SQL Server Express started

Comment: I guess this is not the right community to ask this question.

Comment: No i found many question related connection . but didnt find my answer

Comment: try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine#testing-a-local-connection

Comment: Try 'localhost' instead of the server name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They is because due to we find any updates to Windows like OS , Security Update .

System need to be re-started .
because we are trying to connect to Windows authentication .

The issue is resolved now .